# express app routing mechanism serves file

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I am new to express.js and I have a question about routing. I am implementing a tutorial. In `app.js` the tutorial requires the router file 
`var photos = require('./routes/photos');`

this is what is inside `photos.js`

```
var photos = [];

photos.push({
    name: 'Node.js Logo',
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/images/logos/nodejs-green.png'
});

photos.push({
    name: 'Ryan Speaking',
    path: 'http://nodejs.org/images/ryan-speaker.jpg'
});

exports.list = function(req, res){
    res.render('photos', {
    title: 'Photos',
    photos: photos
    });
};
```

then the tutorial uses the list function 
`app.use('/', photos.list);`

and this is the view directory `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));`

Now, the photos view, `index.ejs` is inside a subdirectory

```
views
    photos
       index.ejs
```

In views directory there is another file named `index.ejs`

```
views
     index.ejs
```

I am just following the tutorial. I didint altered anything. Everything works fine. The tutorial do not spefically difines where exactly the `index.ejs` is. So how express automatically renders the right one? The `views > photos > index` instead of the `views > index` ?

Comment: Maybe you're giving the appropriate path while rendering the template?

Answer (score 0):

Express [does that](https://github.com/strongloop/express/blob/a8a8564459688bdc0b2653da2f28a4fefde7dfdb/lib/view.js#L148-L154) automatically if the path points to a directory instead of a file. This is similar to how node will look for `index.*` files if you try to `require()` a directory.